# How to make vim with tree representation for indents, similliar to result of terminals "tree" command?

Tags: vim, sublimetext3, text-editor

I'm looking for some way to connect indets into tree structure similliar to the one used by terminal tree command.
 [image]

Something that interprets the indents in same way tree interprets file system.
Alternatively for sublime text or another text editor.

Edit: Apologies for the broadness of question, to specify what i wanna do is>
Rather then replacing the actuall text i just want it to interpet the indents into the tree structure while retaining the actuall file should retain it's indents.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says very clearly you can't ask this sort of question here.  See the section with the numbered list, specifically item #4 in that list.

Comment: Okey. I fixed that and specified my problem, thanks for warning me. I didn't take that into account since there is so many similiar questions about text editors.

Comment: This is a far different question than what you first asked. This question would have been fine, but it's not what you asked (and I commented on) before.

Comment: The goal of the question is still the same as before. The only thing that change that before i did not include the fact that i am indenting to make my own if there is no other option.

Comment: The question previously asked for a text editor recommendation, which is why I referred you to the help center guidelines. The edited version does not ask for that recommendation. See for yourself in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47816624/revisions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've asked a broad question (and did not show any research effort so far), so I all I can do is answering it broadly as well (for Vim):

#### permanent change

For a permanent change of the actual text, all you need is `:substitute`. A start would be

```
:%substitute/    \ze\S/└── /
```

To make this more beautiful, another pass could turn `└` into `├` by comparing previous and current line; `:substitute` or `:global` can do this.

#### just visualization

If you don't want to actually manipulate the buffer contents, but just affect the visual appearance, `:set list` and the `'listchars'` option come to mind. Unfortunately, though this can display spaces and tabs, it does so uniformly; i.e. you cannot just apply it to the "last" part of the indent. You have a chance to implement this with `:help conceal`; this can translate a (sequence of) character(s) to a single (different) character. This is based on syntax highlighting. You could define matches for *fourth last space before non-whitespace* and conceal that as `└`, and *third and second last space before non-whitespace* and conceal as `─`, for example.

#### or a hybrid

Another approach would be a combination: Use (easier) modification with `:substitute`, but undo this before writing (with `:autocmd` hooks into the `BufWritePre` and `BufWritePost` events). If this is purely for viewing, you could also simply `:setlocal nomodifiable` or `:setlocal buftype=nowrite` to disallow editing / saving.

Comment: Well to be honest i just started learning vim's syntax about half an hour before i asked the question, which is why i asked, so i knwo what direction to go in. Does conceal allow for matching index at another line? To check if another symbol fulfils the conditions above, if yes match to `├`else `└`? Or is there only regex (which as far as i know doesn't allow matching at specific index, or at east dont knwo how)

Comment: First, that's pretty advanced stuff if you're new to Vim [scripting]. You can use regular expressions to refer to indent one line above the current location (with `\n` and a lookbehind (`\@<=`). Also, you can match individual locations (lines and columns) with `\%l` and `\%v`, but then you need to update the conceal syntax on buffer changes.

Comment: Well i was looking for some text editor that would have this form of structure and i didn't find one so gotta make it myself. And was so far the only idea i had with use of substitute, checking previous line and determining teh symbol. And wouldn't i need to conceal syntax on buffer changed either way when i am changing the visualization?

Comment: Before you invest any serious effort here, please have a look at the similar plugins: [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine) and [vim indent guides](https://github.com/nathanaelkane/vim-indent-guides). Using conceal is tricky, especially with existing syntax highlighting.

Comment: I have something similiar to that already, but i wanted the tree like structure in order to write down logical structures rather then coding itself. These do not highlight the logical structure as much, rather the indentations in code.

Comment: Okey that didn't make much sense. I mean the logical structure between parts of code, but it didn't seem to me as a good representation for some logical structures